# Auto adjust div to background image height using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I am trying to get the background image to resize dynamically using JavaScript to get the height of the image and set the height of a div on a page. Not sure why this isn't working

Any help would be much appreciated.

My current code:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Building Layout - Drag and Drop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="mainScripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="background-image">


<div>
<!--Drag and Drop tiles go here-->
</div>
</div>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#background-image {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('background-image').style.height = this.height;
}
img.src = 'floorplan.jpg';
```

Comment: Do you want to resize this dynamically as the viewport size changes? Or does it just need to be the correct size on initial load?

Comment: Correct size on initial load. This is for an embedded desktop application with a fixed viewport

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to provide "px" after the number for this.height, like this:

```
document.getElementById('background-image').style.height = this.height + "px";
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work. Do you have a fiddle or something where you can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I know you want javascript but maybe you are opened to an only css solution as well. This should solve your issue easily.

```css
.image {
  background: url('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you know if there is a way to keep the native height and width of the background image and still make sure the fill thing displays without resizing it based on the viewport?